# Magento 2 Braintree AVS check not working in REST API

Tags: magento2, api, braintree

Using this API
https://www.domainname.com/index.php/rest/V1/carts/
mine/payment-information

AVS and CVV verification are enabled at Braintree end but when credit card zip code and billing address zip codes do not match Magento still generates the Order but it should not.

Can anyone help with this?